# Prove that $\gcd(a,0)=|a|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I wish to prove a property of the $\gcd$, namely: $\gcd(a,0)=|a|$.

Notice that for some $x,y$ we know that $\gcd(a,0)= ax+  0 \cdot y$ such that $\gcd(a,0)$ is a multiple of $a$. How do we make the step to |a|?

Comment: Because part of the definition of gcd is that it is a *positive* integer ?

Comment: okay so then we have that $\gcd(a,0)=ka$ for $a \geq 0, k>0$

Comment: But $k$ cannot be greater than 1, as this would mean that the number that divides $a$ is greater than $a$ itself.

Comment: Therefore $\gcd(a,0)=|a|$.

Comment: Since $0$ is a multiple of every integer, you just need to look at the divisors of $a$.

Comment: You should specify that $a \ne 0$.  $\gcd(0,0)$ is not defined.

Comment: @gandalf61$\gcd$ does not have to be an integer.  The $\gcd(\frac 12, 2\frac 14) = \frac 14$.  And it isn't the definition that $\gcd$ need be positive but a *trivial* consequence.  If $a|b$ then $-a|b$ and one of $\pm a$ is positive and a positive value is larger than a negative.

Comment: The thing is if $a > 0$ I don't think stating "the largest divisor of $a$ is $a$ itself" should be difficult for anyone.  (right?)  It's just tossing in negatives make for tedious lawyering boilerplate.  But it is trivial.  If $b|a$ then $-b|a$ so $b$ is divisor iff $|b|$ is a divisor and $b \le |b|$.  Tedious to say that *every* time but... it's obviously true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are also two more results that can be used to prove such claim:

> $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b+ka), k \in \mathbb{Z}.$
>
> $gcd(a,a) = a$

Comment: Isn't $\gcd(a,a) = |a|$?  After all.  $\gcd(-3,-3) = 3$.  Of course one can say wolog assume all values are positive......  I think 90% of the OP's issue is the negatives are tripping them up.

Comment: @fleablood Is the gcd a positive integer by definition?

Comment: As positives are larger than negatives and you can't have a negative divisor without having a coresponding positive divisor, it is a *trivial* consequence but not a definition.  Likewise it's trivial that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(|a|,|b|) = \gcd (\pm a, \pm b)$. But if $a$ is not positive then $\gcd(a,a)$ *will* be positive.  So $\gcd(a,a)=\gcd(|a|,|a|) = |a| = -a$. ...  If $a$ is negative.

Answer (score 3):

> Basic fact. If $a \ne 0$. The largest value that divides $a$ is $|a|$.

This shouldn't surprise anyone.  $|a| =  \pm 1*a$ so $|a|$ divides $a$ and for any $x > |a|$ then if $x*r = a$ then $\pm x*r =|a|$ and $\pm r = \frac {|a|}x < \frac {|a|}{|a|} = 1$.  So $1 < r < -1$.  The only  way $r$ can be an integer is if $r = 0$ and $x*0 = 0 = a$.  But we stated that $a \ne 0$.

Allowing for negative factors is a bit of a pain but... for positive values this is obvious and negatives is jsut "special cases".

(The definition of $x$ divides $a$ is that there exists an integer $m$ so that $x*m = a$.)

> Basic fact.  All numbers divide $0$.

This should surprise *everyone* the first time the see it but it makes perfect sense if you think about it.  $0 = x*0$ and $0$ is an integer so every number divides $0$.

So in plain english:

> If $a\ne 0$ then $\gcd(a,0) = |a|$.

If $a \ne 0$ then $\gcd(a,0)$ is the largest value that divides both $a$ and $0$.  As all values divide $0$ this is just the largest value that divides $a$.  And that is $|a|$.

This only seems weird for the same reason "all values divide $0$" seems weird.  Once you see what this *literally* means it should be obvious.

Note, if you do not stipulate $a \ne 0$ the statement is not true.  $\gcd(0,0)$ must be undefined.  As all values divide $0$ there can't be any largest.

Answer (score 0):

Since the gcd has to be positive and cannot be greater than $a$,  Notice $0<\gcd(a,0)\leq |a|$, however, $gcd(a,0) =|k a|$ so $0< |ka| \leq |a|$, which must mean that $k=1$, such that $\gcd(a,0)=|a|$.